# Writing to file, file being used by another process

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, writefile

Alright, so I can't figure out why I can't write to a file. It says it's being used by another process. Here's the error (IOException was unhandled):

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Temp\TempFile.cfg' because it is being used by another process.
```

Here's the current code I'm using to write to the file:

```
Dim myConfig
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Configuration Files (*.cfg)|*.cfg"
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        myConfig = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        If (myConfig IsNot Nothing) Then
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, TextBox1_Output_Module.Text & vbCrLf & TextBox2_Output_Module.Text & vbCrLf & TextBox3_Output_Module.Text)
            myConfig.Close()
        End If
    End If
```

I'm not sure what I am missing as I thought I tested this yesterday and it worked.

Comment: That's what I don't know. I'm trying to write to a file that hasn't been created yet, so its not like I'm overwriting a file that already exists that might be open in another program like Notepad or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here's what I ended up doing, seems to be working just fine as is. I took out the if condition and left everything else as is. I can always code for the cancel later on.

```
    Dim myConfig
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Configuration Files (*.cfg)|*.cfg"
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, TextBox1_Output_Module.Text & vbCrLf & TextBox2_Output_Module.Text & vbCrLf & TextBox3_Output_Module.Text)
```

This codes for the ok/cancel button.

```
    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, TextBox1_Output_Module.Text & vbCrLf & TextBox2_Output_Module.Text & vbCrLf & TextBox3_Output_Module.Text)
    End If
```

Comment: What happen if the user press Cancel on the SaveDialog?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that the process that keep the file open is your own process.
When you call saveDialog1.OpenFile(), you are opening the file and a stream is returned.
Then you call WriteAllText() that tries to open again the same file resulting in the exception above.
You could solve simply removing the call to OpenFile()

```
   If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then 
       File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, TextBox1_Output_Module.Text & vbCrLf & TextBox2_Output_Module.Text & vbCrLf & TextBox3_Output_Module.Text) 
   End If
```

Just keep in mind that WriteAllText() creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the **target file already exists**, it is overwritten.